# How to identify and terminate a javascript in infinite loop programmatically?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

It is more of a hypothetical question. There is sometimes a possibility of a javascript code entering an infinite loop and blocking everything specially in early stages of development. I know the best solution would be to code so that such a situation never arises but what if in a certain case it is impossible to write a fullproof code (maybe because we don't have control on the input or something else).

Is there any way we can programmatically determine when a code is in an infinite loop and terminate it?

Maybe running the pieces of code where such a thing could happen in a separate thread or in a child process synchronously and determining when that thread/process is in an infinite loop.

How could one go about doing that? Is it possible to determine when a thread (either main or child) is in an infinite loop by determining the CPU usage by that thread alone?

Based on the discussion had in comments below I realise that identifying a blocking infinite loop would be impossible on the basis of tracking repetitive execution of similar statements  and high resource utilization alone. So I think that the solution lies in a combination of both. But that brings as back to our earlier problem. How can we gauge the CPU usage by a script?

Comment: Is is this an issue you encounter on a regular basis? Even if it is, a good way to tell is if the browser becomes unresponsive and then offers to terminate your script.

Comment: Its called a halting problem and read description here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem. In short it can never be determined whether program terminites for some given input

Comment: @dlev Though I face such problems but they are always easily resolved. Mostly they are my own mistake. The question I asked was more for a hypothetical reason. And I want to do it programmatically for only that thread, not all the scripts in the page

Comment: @TejasPatel the halting probllem is about a scenario when a process runs indefinitely but may or may not block other programs from running. I was interested in cases where the infinite loop blocks everything else, the bad kind of infinite loops. That is why I was thinking along the lines of CPU usgae.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "only that thread", javascript is single threaded, and that's the problem, you're blocking that thread with faulty code that never finishes, and when the thread is blocked you don't really have any way of running more javascript to resolve the blocking as the one and only thread is blocked. This is usually never an issue, as scripts that block the thread this way happens because the developer made a mistake, and the only way to resolve it is to fix the faulty code.

Comment: @adeneo ok then i will retract the part about "only that thread". Is there a way to gracefully terminate the script? With an appropriate error message or something. Or starting some other script instead?

Comment: No there is not, once you've made such an error the browser stops responding, and there's no way in javascript you can tell wether or not the browser stopped responding, or do anything about it. Again, the only solution is to make sure this doesn't happen, which shouldn't be very hard to do.

Comment: @Surender: The problem is that you *can't* detect whether it's gone into an infinite loop or not in the general case. I'm not sure what you were saying when you said that the halting problem applied to programs that "may or may not block other programs from running", since the halting problem is unrelated to concurrency. The halting problem *does* apply here, and it is in general impossible.

Comment: @TejasPatel: Wrong. Please read exactly. The theorem states that *not for all* programs & inputs it can be determined whether they halt, instead of "it can *never* be determined". In practise, for most programs & inputs it can be determined, and some programs can even be proven to halt for all posssible inputs.

Comment: @icktoofay I didn't meant the "may or may not block other programs from running" part in the context of concurrency. I meant it in terms of rendering the browser unresponsive and hence stopping any subsequent code from running. The halting problem does not takes into account the resource utilization by the code, it works on lengthy iteration of same or similar statements. I think the solution may lie in the resource utilization measurement and hence my belief that the halting problem does not applies here.

Comment: @Surender: So you're not actually trying to detect infinite loops, but rather code that is taking a long time to execute (even if it would otherwise halt)? If so, edit your question.

Comment: @icktoofay Nope i want to detect infinite loops but not on the basis of the time taken in execution but rather on the basis of its resource utilization. Or a better way would be to determine it on the basis of combination of 1. repetitive execution of same statements and 2. high resource utilization.

Comment: @Surender: So you're looking for loops whose bodies execute a large number of times and are taking a long time to execute? Again, that is different from detecting infinite loops (equivalent to the halting problem), and if that is your question, please edit your question. Otherwise, please edit to clarify what it is, because as I interpret it as is, it is impossible because of the halting problem.

Comment: @icktoofay No I am lookinng for loops "whose bodies execute a large number of times, which utilise a lot of resources and are taking a long time to execute".  I am not saying that these conditions conclusively define a blocking infinite loop but if there is a better way to define one then please share.

Comment: Wont the browser itself offer to terminate the thread which is running infinitely?? But to answer your question if a thread is running infinitely, the easiest solution is to get another thread to terminate it but this option is not available in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ash The browser would not give us an option for a graceful termination. It will just stop everything without allowing any housekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

For simple loops you can use approach used  [here](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Etinelli/classes/AR-group/readingsS04/jZhang-APAQS01.pdf) . It uses path based approach to detect infinite loop. Statements are considered as nodes of graph.

You can also see this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5431775). They have implemented run time solution for java program.

Answer (score 0):

Given there are no other viable/sophisticated solutions proposed, a low-tech solution is to just use a counter and abort if it reaches an absurdly high number.

This requires manual coding effort, but can be useful for debugging an infinite loop when you know it is already happening.

```
var count = 0

while(true){
  if(count++>100000){
      //assume infinite loop, exit to avoid locking up browser while debugging
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: A nice work around but with obvious downfalls. What if the body of the loop contains some very costly code (resource utilisation wise), then by the time we reach that absurdly high number the browser would already have become unresponsive.

Comment: This solution makes very little sense: why bother cluttering your code with a counter when a) very few of your loops are going to randomly be endless, b) the ones that do will be caught immediately when the page becomes unresponsive, and c) if you're going to spend time, it might as well be spent actually analyzing if your code is correct.

Comment: This is just temporary debugging code which can be removed when you have resolved the issue definitively. Sometimes complicated/3rd-party/asynchronous libraries can be involved which require a few attempts to resolve properly. The 20 seconds of coding time required to add and remove this code could sometimes be useful to avoid repeated script timeouts and browser lockups. You could also set a breakpoint to debug when the "infinite" loop condition is true.

Comment: If infinite loops are a problem then code is not complete. That's why I proposed a solution to efficiently debug the underlying issue.